# How do I retain git history and project location in eclipse on windows when moving from 2 drives to 1?

Tags: eclipse, installation, egit

In my previous eclipse setup I had the workspace and git repositories on the D drive. I've chosen not to partition the new drive and have copied the old workspace and git repository folders to the C drive.

After a fresh install of kepler I've found that the projects not under git moved ok while the one under git didn't. The properties of this project showed a location of drive D, while the other projects showed the new location of drive C.

I'm using egit bundled with eclipse. I've tried importing the project but this loses git history. I would like to retain git history as if the drive move never happened. I'm using a remote repository and can pull from that, but that doesn't keep my local history.

Since I chose the workspace to be the C drive rather than the D drive eclipse was path relative and picked it up for the non-git projects. But for git projects it looks like eclipse is using an absolute path, and hence the issue with project location.

I can swap drives around to get back to the old setup if needed. Any suggestions that will allow me to move the project as if the move never happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the projects from the workspace (without deleting content), and then import them from the new location (using *Import* > *Existing Projects into Workspace*). After that, if the projects are not yet connected to the Git repository they're in, right-click them and select *Team* > *Share Project...*.

Comment: It worked, but in an odd way. Initially it didn't show git history (as before when I tried), but when I right clicked the project to see if sharing it would make a difference the history screen filled in before I selected anything. As it turned out _Team > Share Project_ wasn't available so the import picked up on that. Don't know the reason for that one.